# How to fix Connection reset by 140.82.112.4 port 22 for git local connection to github remote?

Tags: git, github, ssh

My local computer is using win10, gitbash client, before the local repository and github remote repository can communicate normally via ssh in both directions(pull/clone or push etc), but this time when I pull the remote code to update locally, I get an error.

```
git pull origin main
Connection reset by 140.82.112.4 port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

---

I then tried the following command to see if it worked.

```
 ssh -vT git@github.com -A
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Administrator/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/Administrator/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.112.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-25270101
debug1: no match: babeld-25270101
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection reset by 140.82.112.4 port 22
```

---

It was also tested using the following command.

```
ping github.com
正在 Ping github.com [140.82.112.4] 具有 32 字节的数据:
来自 140.82.112.4 的回复: 字节=32 时间=222ms TTL=44
来自 140.82.112.4 的回复: 字节=32 时间=222ms TTL=44
来自 140.82.112.4 的回复: 字节=32 时间=222ms TTL=44
来自 140.82.112.4 的回复: 字节=32 时间=222ms TTL=44
140.82.112.4 的 Ping 统计信息:
数据包: 已发送 = 4，已接收 = 4，丢失 = 0 (0% 丢失)，
往返行程的估计时间(以毫秒为单位):
最短 = 222ms，最长 = 222ms，平均 = 222ms
```

Also I have tried regenerating the ssh key and then copying the public key correctly into the ssh configuration of my GitHub account as well, the local computer `.ssh/config` file reads as follows

```
  Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ForwardAgent yes
```

The result is still unsuccessful.
Does it seem to be connected properly? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Are you using an antivirus or firewall other than the Windows default?  Are you using any sort of proxy, MITM device, or monitoring software?  If so, does completely uninstalling it and rebooting fix the problem?

Comment: I didn't install any additional anti-virus or firewall software, but strangely enough it works fine today. Please note that I didn't do anything! The computer has been in standby mode until now. thank your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh -vT git@github.com -A`: you are not supposed to use agent forwarding with `github.com` itself.

The test should be:

```bash
# Attempt to SSH in to github
  ssh -T git@github.com
> Hi USERNAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide
> shell access.
```

Check the ["Using SSH agent forwarding" documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/using-ssh-agent-forwarding) and see if it applies to your case.

Note: `/c/Users/Administrator/.ssh/config`: it is best practice to *not* use your Windows Adminnistrator account, but rather your personal named account with which you initially logged to your Windows session.

Comment: Strangely enough it now works properly. Please note that I didn't do anything! The computer has been on standby since I asked this question until now. `ssh -T git@github.com` and `ssh -T git@github.com -A` are all passed!

Comment: @xingcui Great: if you see `Hi USERNAME!`, then the clone should be able to proceed.